# Compacting a substitution cipher key

Tags: keys, key-size, substitution-cipher

In a substitution cipher, I recieve 3 bits and than I return another 3 bits.
The key of this cipher could be a matrix represented as:

```
(0) 0 0 0 => 0 1 1

(1) 0 0 1 => 1 0 1

(2) 0 1 0 => 1 1 1

(3) 0 1 1 => 0 1 0

(4) 1 0 0 => 0 0 1

(5) 1 0 1 => 1 0 0

(6) 1 1 0 => 0 0 0

(7) 1 1 1 => 1 1 0
```

So, when we receive `000`, the cipher will return `011`.

When we receive `101`, the cipher will return `100`.

The key itself can be represented as a stream of 24 bits like this:

```
0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
```

Is there a way to reduce the key to 15 bits?

I other words, can that matrix representation of 24 bits, could be represented with 15 bits?

Comment: That's not a key, that's a permutation from ${\{0,1}\}^3$ to ${\{0,1\}}^3$. And it is identical to performing XOR with `1` for each bit, also known as a bit complement.

Comment: Maarten Bodewes, my key example was unfortunate... I changed there to a random mapping

Comment: OK, now it is a random permutation from ${\{0,1\}}^3$ to ${\{0,1\}}^3$, helped you a bit with the edit. I presume any random permutation is allowed.

Answer (score 2):

Not quite, if all possible permutations are allowed.

There are $8! = 40320$ permutations over 3 bits; 15 bits of key allows you to specify $2^{15} = 32768$ of them; hence any mapping of 15 bits will necessarily $40320-32768 = 7552$ of permutations unexpressable.

It is doable if you don't allow every single permutation (e.g. allow only even permutations), or if you allow 16 bits of keying data.